# find the value of |a+b|

Tags: systems-of-equations, cubics

Can anyone help me with this? I really have a hard time solving the problem.

> Give $7a^2+3a^2b+14ab-2ab^2=61$ and $7b^2-3a^2b+2ab^2=2$, find the value of |a+b|.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to solve the problem. First look at the equations carefully. They have something in common, and these must mean something.

$$7a^2+3a^2b+14ab-2ab^2=61 --- (1)$$ 
$$7b^2-3a^2b+2ab^2=2 -------(2)$$

If you add equations (1) and (2), you get $$7a^2+14ab+7b^2=63 -----(3)$$
which means that $$7(a+b)^2=63-------(4)$$
Then you can find the value of |a+b|.